# docker-compose up --build hang at chown in entrypoint without error. How to resolve?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to change the ownership of a mounted volume at startup so that a user in the container can write to it and the host can read from it.

```
    volumes:
      - '../local/userData:/userData'
```

seems to be accepted - a folder is created in local/userData, but as root.
`sudo chown -R user:user /userData` in the entryPoint command seems to fail and hang without an error. How can one resolve this?

```
...
services:
  myservice:
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: myservice-container/Dockerfile
    image: myservice:latest
    container_name: local_myservice_1
    networks:
      - local_default
    volumes:
      - '../local/userData:/userData'
    environment:
      DEPLOY_TYPE: local
      AWS_ENVIRONMENT: NOT_AWS
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    # Make /userData writeable to user.
    entrypoint: sh -c "(ls -la /userData) && (sudo chown -R user:user /userData) && (echo OK)"
```

The dockerfile successfully created the user already:

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash user
```

The whole process hangs with:

```
Recreating myservice_1 ... done
Attaching to myservice_1
myservice_1  | total 8
myservice_1  | drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Jul 29 15:20 .
myservice_1  | drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Jul 29 15:27 ..
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker events -> <docker.types.daemon.CancellableStream object at 0x7f7b815604f0>
....<hangs here> ....
^C
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
^Ccompose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=False, filters={'label': ['com.docker.compose.project=local', 'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 1 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['-c',
          '(ls -la /userData) && (sudo chown -R user:user /userData) && (echo '
          'OK)'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['sh',
...
Killing myservice_1    ... 
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: {<Container: local_ai_1 (7f39ec)>}
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Starting producer thread for <Container: myservice_1 (7f39ec)>
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker kill <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['-c',
          '(ls -la /userData) && (sudo chown -R user:user /userData) && (echo '
          'OK)'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['sh',
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker kill -> None
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker stop -> None
Killing myservice_1    ... done
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker wait -> {'Error': None, 'StatusCode': 137}
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['-c',
          '(ls -la /userData) && (sudo chown -R user:user /userData) && (echo '
          'OK)'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['sh',
...
compose.parallel.feed_queue: Pending: set()
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container <- ('7f39ec0d3a5019b72ff42b13eb7a0353c420c35738c0be5d6a4f80b95fde8102')
ERROR: compose.cli.main.exit_with_metrics: 2
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_container -> {'AppArmorProfile': 'docker-default',
 'Args': ['-c',
          '(ls -la /userData) && (sudo chown -R user:user /userData) && (echo '
          'OK)'],
 'Config': {'AttachStderr': False,
            'AttachStdin': False,
            'AttachStdout': False,
            'Cmd': None,
            'Domainname': '',
            'Entrypoint': ['sh',
```

"OK" is not printed. I'm running `docker-compose --verbose up --build`

---

Did not solve: [docker-compose up hangs forever. How to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941911/docker-compose-up-hangs-forever-how-to-debug) , [docker-compose up error without information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71435415/docker-compose-up-error-without-information) , [Docker compose & docker-entrypoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52942913/docker-compose-docker-entrypoint) , [docker-compose up hangs forever. How to debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59941911/docker-compose-up-hangs-forever-how-to-debug)

Comment: I wonder if it's waiting for you to type in a `sudo` password.  There probably is no correct password, and also there is no way to enter it.  You shouldn't usually need `sudo` in Docker; specify `user: root` in the Compose file if you need that level of permission and the image sets a different user by default.

Comment: That's a good thought. "sudo ls" also fails in the same way.
However "chown" without sudo results in operation not permitted.

Comment: The container does create the directory on the host, as root. I can chown it from the host to the UID=1000 user and its all works fine. 
However, think means running docker (to create the directory) and it failing (because sudo failed), and running it again. Its a mess for CI automation  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution was to always have the host create that folder, and not leave it up to docker-compose. If docker-compose creates it, it is created as root.